# Avoiding indent in the new line when writing a long sentence in an algorithm

Tags: indentation, algorithm2e

When writing a long sentence inside my algorithm, I am getting an indent in the new line. Is there a way to aviod this indent without creating a new number in this line? I am using the package algorithm2e.

What I get:
[image]

What I want to get:
[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}[H]

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[p]
    Determine parameters:\\
    Now the algortihm tries to find a way to sort the parameters in some order following the list.\\
    loadList(parameters);
    startFunction();\\
\caption{New Method}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reasons the `noalgohanging` option does not work as expected. Anyway you can avoid the hanging with

```
\SetAlgoHangIndent{0pt}
```

Here is a mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}[H]
\SetAlgoHangIndent{0pt}
\begin{document}
 
 \begin{algorithm}[p]
  Determine parameters:\\
  Now the algortihm tries to find a way to sort the parameters in some order following the list.\\
  loadList(parameters);
  startFunction();\\
  \caption{New Method}
 \end{algorithm}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]