# Add space in front of line in algorithm

Tags: spacing, indentation, algorithms, line

I need to add an indent in front of 'climate' and 'each region' so that the overflowing lines aren't confused for a new line of pseudocode. [image] I have tried everything including [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37181/linebreak-in-package-algorithm2e) (the algorithm2e package wasn't working for me for some reason) and I've tried the usual `\`  to add a space, `$\thinmuskip$`, `\indent` to add an indent, and other things that didn't work. My latex code is below

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
initialisation: choose initial emission control rates $\boldsymbol{\mu^k}=[\mu^k(1) \ ... \ \mu^k(Tmax)]$ for each region $k \in 1,...,12$;
store initial $\boldsymbol{\mu} ^k$ in vector $CR$;

\For{\textup{each region $i \in 1,...,12$}}{{\nosemic find $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$ that maximises $\sum_{t=1}^{Tmax} U[c^{i}(t), L^{i}(t)]R(t)$ subject to economic and \;
 climate equations, with all other $\boldsymbol{\mu} ^k$ fixed from $CR$;

replace the old value of $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$ in $CR$ with the new optimal $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$;
}
}
\While{\textup{|$\boldsymbol{\mu^i}-\boldsymbol{\mu^j}$|>threshold for some regions $i,j$}}{
{repeat \textbf{for} loop\;
}
}
\caption{Noncooperative Equilibrium for RICE}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you make the example compilable?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: For instance, you might want to make the file start with`\documentclass{article}` and end with `\end{document}` and include `\usepackage{xxx}` for necessary packages like `algorithm2e` to ensure that your .tex file is compilable.

Comment: I see, thank you, I will do that

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of what is requested here: [Avoiding indent in the new line when writing a long sentence in an algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581839/5764), with an adjustment using `\SetAlgoHangIndent{<len>}` providing the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I still have trouble compiling your example. But I guess there is quick hack for your question: Just insert something like `\phantom{for}` in front of the word climate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
initialisation: choose initial emission control rates $\boldsymbol{\mu^k}=[\mu^k(1) \ ... \ \mu^k(Tmax)]$ for each region $k \in 1,...,12$;
store initial $\boldsymbol{\mu} ^k$ in vector $CR$;

\For{\textup{each region $i \in 1,...,12$}}{{\nosemic find $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$ that maximises $\sum_{t=1}^{Tmax} U[c^{i}(t), L^{i}(t)]R(t)$ subject to economic and \;
 \phantom{for} climate equations, with all other $\boldsymbol{\mu} ^k$ fixed from $CR$;

replace the old value of $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$ in $CR$ with the new optimal $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$;
}
}
\While{\textup{|$\boldsymbol{\mu^i}-\boldsymbol{\mu^j}$|>threshold for some regions $i,j$}}{
{repeat \textbf{for} loop\;
}
}
\caption{Noncooperative Equilibrium for RICE}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do `\SetAlgoHangIndent{1.5em}` (or whatever length you deem good). I also suggest other changes to avoid clumsy input and for consistency.

Note that you should not load `algorithm2e` and `algorithm` together.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetAlgoHangIndent{1.5em}
\SetArgSty{textnormal}
\textbf{initialisation:} choose initial emission control rates 
  $\boldsymbol{\mu}^k=[\mu^k(1) \dots \mu^k(T_{\mathrm{max}})]$
  for each region $k \in 1,\dots,12$; store initial
  $\boldsymbol{\mu}^k$ in vector $CR$;

\For{each region $i \in 1,\dots,12$}{%
  find $\boldsymbol{\mu}^i$ that maximises
  $\sum_{t=1}^{T_{\mathrm{max}}} U[c^{i}(t), L^{i}(t)]R(t)$ subject to economic and
  climate equations, with all other $\boldsymbol{\mu}^k$ fixed from $CR$;

  replace the old value of $\boldsymbol{\mu^i}$ in $CR$ with the new optimal
  $\boldsymbol{\mu}^i$;
}

\While{$|\boldsymbol{\mu}^i-\boldsymbol{\mu}^j|> \text{threshold}$ for some regions $i,j$}{%
{repeat \textbf{for} loop;}
}
\caption{Noncooperative Equilibrium for RICE}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]